# Go Matrix Application problem in Backpropagation algorithm

Tags: go, matrix, neural-network, apply, backpropagation

I have been researching into Neural Networks and was trying to take a shot at creating one with great help from [Michael Nielsen's book on Neural Networks](http://neuralnetworksanddeeplearning.com/) *([pdf](https://static.latexstudio.net/article/2018/0912/neuralnetworksanddeeplearning.pdf))*

I am basically converting his first network python file into a Go application. My main problem has arisen in the back propagation function. In this function we feed forward through the network keeping track of a list of z matrices and a list of activation matrices:

```
//Defintions above
for i := 0; i < len(nn.weights); i++ {
    var z mat.Dense
    weights := nn.weights[i]
    biases := nn.biases[i]
    z.Mul(weights, a)
    z.Add(&z, biases)
    zs[i] = &z
    applySigmoid := func(_, _ int, v float64) float64 {
        return sigmoid(v)
    }

    z.Apply(applySigmoid, &z)
    a = &z
    activations[i] = a
}
```

However this is not the main problem. The main problem arises after. Starting the back propagation we define delta equal to the cost_derivative of the last activation matrix and the label y. After we apply the sigmoid derivative function to the last z matrix. Then after you multiply the delta matrix with the z matrix. The problem arises when applying the sigmoid prime function to the z matrix. It changes the value of the delta matrix aswell. This is what the output looks like before and after the application of sigmoid prime:

```
0xc0000120d8
⎡0.09982711116022883⎤
⎢0.24260080224285077⎥
⎢0.15233709720227542⎥
⎢0.19494995716396032⎥
⎢0.15726110223847964⎥
⎢0.11059359868590982⎥
⎢0.17026207248890898⎥
⎢0.15609114217030096⎥
⎢ -0.810915969767469⎥
⎣0.15840349924957667⎦
11111111111111111111111111
0xc0000120d8
⎡ 0.2493781922654036⎤
⎢0.24635733720120548⎥
⎢ 0.2485551795164905⎥
⎢0.24763962253727612⎥
⎢0.24846065795203182⎥
⎢0.24923712159141503⎥
⎢0.24819689472860218⎥
⎢ 0.2484833845383838⎥
⎢ 0.2130189186834713⎥
⎣0.24843830572599868⎦
22222222222222222222222222
```

Here is the code that is being run in that section:

```
delta := nn.cost_derivative(activations[len(activations)-1], y)

fmt.Println(&delta)
fmt.Println(mat.Formatted(delta))
fmt.Println("11111111111111111111111111")
applySigmoidPrime := func(_, _ int, v float64) float64 {
    return sigmoidPrime(v)
}
zs[len(zs)-1].Apply(applySigmoidPrime, zs[len(zs)-1])

fmt.Println(&delta)
fmt.Println(mat.Formatted(delta))
fmt.Println("22222222222222222222222222")
delta.MulElem(delta, zs[len(zs)-1])
nabla_b[len(nabla_b)-1] = delta
nabla_w[len(nabla_w)-1].Mul(delta, activations[len(activations)-1].T())
time.Sleep(100000000000)
```

I have also printed the memory address to the zs[len(zs)-1] and it is different then the delta memory address and am just very confused on why delta is being changed.

I have tried applying temporary matrices to no avail. I have also tried looping through the apply instead of using GoNum's built in apply function. Still delta is being changed hindering the actual adjusting of the weights and biases causing it to diminish and never actually properly adjust. I am assuming it has something to do with memory but as I am fairly new to working with memory, I am at a standstill.

The main problem/question is why is delta being changed when zs[len(zs-1)-1].Apply is being called?

Comment: This is a rather long text, can you add the concrete question at the end? I am not quite able to see what your actual problem is.

Comment: Added the main point at the end, first time posting here should've gotten straight to the point!